# How to insert an list one by one(Looping over forl loop) to a dictionary of list in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, hash

I am looping over list and appending the dictionary of list in c# but it appends only the last value of forloop

```
class Crawl
{
    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
        var variations_hash = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        foreach(var item1 in arr1)
        {
            variations_hash["v_id_1"] = item1;
        }
        foreach (var job in variations_hash) 
        {
            foreach (string jobs in job.Value) 
            {
                Console.Write (jobs+"\n");
            }
        }
    }
    . . .
}
```

Result:

```
three
```

Expected result:

```
one
two
three
```

How to append all for loop values one by one(as a list/Array) to dictionary(variations_hash)

Expected structure will be

```
{"v_id_1":"["one","two","three"]"}
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile since `item1` is a `string` and `variations_hash["v_id_1"]` is expecting a `List<string>`

Comment: @juharr: `arr1` is the array. `item1` is the string that the `foreach` is assigning each return from `arr1`'s enumerator to.

Comment: @AlexGravely Yes, I know that.  It's the reason `variations_hash["v_id_1"] = item1;` will not compile because it is assigning a `string` to a `List<string>`.

Comment: @juharr: Whoops, I have no idea why I thought it was iterating the keys, not the values. I need my morning Dr. Pepper.

Comment: @AlexGravely HA, I've already had mine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

1. Add new *key value pair* if key *doesn't exist*
2. Add new item to the corresponding *value* if key *exists*

Let´s just see what should go on:

1. `item1` is `"one"`, there's *no* key `"v_id_1"` so we add a pair: `{"v_id_1", ["one"]}`;
2. `item1` is `"two"`, there *is* a key `"v_id_1"` and we add to the *corresponding value* `{"v_id_1", ["one", "two"]}`;
3. finally, `item1` is `"three"`, there *is* a key `"v_id_1"` and once again we add to the *corresponding value* `{"v_id_1", ["one", "two", "three"]}`;

Implementation could be something like this:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var variations_hash = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach(var item1 in arr1) { 
  List<String> list; 

  if (variations_hash.TryGetValue("v_id_1", out list))
    list.Add(item1);
  else
    variations_hash.Add("v_id_1", new List<String>() {item1}); 
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the whole array to the dictionary instead of looping through it.

```
variations_hash["v_id_1"] = arr1.ToList();
```

Comment: but how can i automate for a bigger data?

Comment: You would have to show what you are talking about. From the question/code you have posted this solves your problem.

Comment: sorry but this is initial question "How to append all for loop values one by one"

Answer (score 0):

the first `foreach` is your problem, you are setting the value of v_id_1 three times instead of adding all three values, try:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var variations_hash = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
variations_hash["v_id_1"] = arr1.ToList();
foreach (var job in variations_hash)
{
    foreach (string jobs in job.Value)
    {
        Console.Write(jobs + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than give you a working code sample, I thought I'd just point you in the right direction.

Since you want a Dictionary with a List as the value, it's easier to think in reverse order. Try getting your List ready first and then adding that List into the Dictionary at the end.

You should notice that you keep resetting the value of your Dictionary with a single item. Since Dictionaries are generic, it doesn't know that you want to append the new value to the value that is currently there. This is why I find it easier to work backwards and then it should fall into place easily.